# How to remove web shops from search results?

Tags: search, search-engines, google-search

Whenever you search information about some product you get bombarded by CEO optimized shopping sites and it is hard to get some real information about some product. If it is a really popular product then just adding +review could help you get closer to what you are looking for, but still with lots of unwanted web shops in results.

If it is not a really mainstream product but still sold on thousands of web shops then it is almost impossible get anything other that web shopping results. Sometimes adding +wordpress or +forum helps, but not always.

So I'm wondering has somebody came up with certain set of query options that would filter out web shops? Maybe something like -shopping -cart ? Yeah, it is not that simple. If there is any search kung-fu master please share your kung-fu :)

Answer (score 1):

If you add -shop to the search you will usually get the worst offenders gone.